# How to detach an ObjectGraph from the Entity Framework Context?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I need a solution on detaching an Entity and his child records from a context.
If i try to detach the parent entity only from a List<> i queried with LINQ to Entities
i lose the child records. If i try to enumerate through the child records and detach them i get an InvalidOperationException.

Is there a solution i miss?